# Freeze in webapplication

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, freeze, lag

Im facing this problem on a Productive system, and I don't know where to look next:

Context: a webapp with REST API, Java, Spring, Hibernate on a Tomcat serer.

- A random method (triggered by a user calling my REST API) freezes about 15min, then returns normally. No ERROR, No Exception.
- Not reproducible, it can happen at any time.
- It can happen on very simple methods: it happened on a one-liner where I call a Spring JPA Repositoy method (so implemented by Spring, not myself).
- I have Javamelody, so I monitor the Database respone times: it is not the Database, not the SQL!
- I have Spring monitoring pointcuts (org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor) so I know that it "hangs" inside of the webapp. As I said earlyer, I see no pattern. It can hang anywhere.

How to go on?

- How can I find out if this is an infrastructure problem or not?
- How can I see what is hanging?
- The funny thing is the similar time: always about 933000ms or about 15min. This sounds like a timeout, but which one because there is no error! Is there any known default timeout of 15min?

Many thanks or your help. Remy

**Edit from 25.11.2016**

The time seems to be lost aquiring the connection:

```
org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - catalina-exec-31 admin 10.226.17.28 - Session Metrics {
    929967181162 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    929967495527 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    449250 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

The hanging thread is doing "getConnection":

```
catalina-exec-31
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native&nbsp;Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.packet.read.ReadPacketFetcher.getReusableBuffer(ReadPacketFetcher.java:166)
org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:900)
org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:604)
org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbStatement.java:261)
org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbStatement.java:383)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:658)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:635)
org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1205)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor159.invoke(Unknown&nbsp;Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.getResultList(Unknown&nbsp;Source)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:110)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.findByType(Unknown&nbsp;Source)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor171.invoke(Unknown&nbsp;Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.invokeUnderTrace(PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.java:62)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:112)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.findByType(Unknown&nbsp;Source)
```

Comment: Take a [thread dump](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_obtain_a_thread_dump_of_my_running_webapp_.3F).

Answer (score 0):

This configuration of dbcp 1.4 solved it.

```
# Database connection pool setup: see http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html
dbcp.maxWait=30000
dbcp.maxIdle=10
dbcp.maxActive=50
dbcp.validationQuery=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
dbcp.testWhileIdle=true
dbcp.testOnReturn=true
dbcp.testOnBorrow=true
dbcp.validationQueryTimeout=2
dbcp.accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true
dbcp.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000
dbcp.numTestsPerEvictionRun=5
dbcp.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
dbcp.removeAbandonedTimeout=60
```

Comment: I know this is old, but can you say just _what_change_ in the above configuration file fixed it?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is old. Here I did some pessimistic connection testing (testWhileIdle, testOnReturn, testOnBorrow) but not 100% this was it. Today my advice is before all to update the driver.